# Import bacpac file into local SQL Server

Tags: azure-sql-server

I'm able to restore a database from a `.bacpac` file using `SqlPackage.exe` import functionality. However is there a way to achieve the same functionality using SQL command?

```
sqlpackage.exe /a:Import
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I knew, we cannot use SQL command(Transact-SQL statements) to import a bacpac file to sql server. If you want to copy a database with  SQL command(Transact-SQL statements), I suggest you use backup and restore. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/copy-databases-to-other-servers?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Jim Xu. There isn't a way can achieve the same functionality using SQL command(T-SQL).

As I searched and we only can find the two ways to import/restore the database to local SQL Server from .bacpac file:

1. [Using the Import Data-tier Application Wizard(SSMS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/import-a-bacpac-file-to-create-a-new-user-database?view=sql-server-ver15#using-the-import-data-tier-application-wizard)
2. [SqlPackage.exe /a:Import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#import-parameters-and-properties).

Hope this helps.